# Select ALL parameters Power automate - Report builder to sharepoint extract flow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, power-automate, powerapps, reportbuilder

I need to use Power Automate to deliver a data exract into a sharepoint location.
I have about 200 parameters and I dont want to start naming each parameter name and value 200 times to be able to export just a single document.

I want to use the select all parameters.
Is there a shortcut to this ?

I tried typing all, but it did not work.

Comment: Please share more details and be a little more specific. 200 parameters to Power Automate? Sounds like you should look into using JSON as one parameter instead of 200 individual ones.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.